# Filtering tables with particular row and colnames

Tags: r

I have a few hundreds of 2*2 table as shown below:

```
$`345`
   N S
N 10 7
K  3 3

$`359`
  N S
P 7 4
S 2 2
```

But i only need to select tables that has "N" in its row and colnames. How can i do this , ifelse did not work...

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example it will be much easier for people to help you. As it is, I can't make any sense of what your data actually look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that work by:

```
> n <- c("M", "N", "O")
> # create a sample data set
> m <- lapply(1:10, function(i)matrix(sample(4), 2, 2, dimnames=list(n[sample(3,2)], n[sample(3,2)])))
> names(m) <- paste(1:10)
> # looks like this
> m
$`1`
  N M
O 1 3
M 2 4

... snip ...

$`10`
  M O
M 1 3
N 4 2

> 
> # filter it
> r <- Filter(function(x) all(sapply(dimnames(x), function(x)"N" %in% x)), m)
> r
$`2`
  M N
O 4 2
N 1 3

$`4`
  O N
N 1 3
O 2 4

$`5`
  M N
N 4 3
O 1 2

$`7`
  M N
O 4 1
N 3 2
```

Comment: How does the filter function work, when i need different column and row , say in this example from row "O" and from column "M" ?